# Swift Timer not firing

Tags: swift, timer

I have the following code for starting and stopping a timer.

```
private var timer: Timer? = nil

private func startTimer() {
    if (timer != nil) {
        return
    }
    logger.error("Starting timer on \(Thread.current)")
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        self.logger.error("Timer fired on \(Thread.current)")
    })
}

private func stopTimer() {
    if (timer == nil) {
        return
    }
    logger.error("Stopping timer on \(Thread.current)")
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

The timer will be started and stopped multiple times.  I'm running into an issue where it starts and stops as expected the first time, but the second time we start the timer it never fires.  Here are the logs I am seeing from two consecutive runs of the application.  You can see that "Timer fired" is never called after running the timer the second time.

Run 1:

```
Starting timer on <_NSMainThread: 0x2829e4140>{number = 1, name = main}
Timer fired on <_NSMainThread: 0x2829e4140>{number = 1, name = main}
Timer fired on <_NSMainThread: 0x2829e4140>{number = 1, name = main}
Timer fired on <_NSMainThread: 0x2829e4140>{number = 1, name = main}
Stopping timer on <_NSMainThread: 0x2829e4140>{number = 1, name = main}
Starting timer on <NSThread: 0x2829ecf00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
```

Run 2:

```
Starting timer on <_NSMainThread: 0x281cb8400>{number = 1, name = main}
Timer fired on <_NSMainThread: 0x281cb8400>{number = 1, name = main}
Timer fired on <_NSMainThread: 0x281cb8400>{number = 1, name = main}
Stopping timer on <_NSMainThread: 0x281cb8400>{number = 1, name = main}
Starting timer on <NSThread: 0x281cbc140>{number = 8, name = (null)}
```

Why does't the timer ever fire the second time around?  The only potential lead I can think of at the moment is with the threads.  Right now the stopping of the timer and the subsequent restarting of it may not happen on the main thread and the documentation for invalidate() says it should be called on the same thread as the timer was started on.  So an additional question is how can I guarantee start and stop are called on the same thread (doesn't need to be the main thread)?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of problems here. One is that you fail to `unlock()` your lock in some cases. If `startTimer` is called twice, I expect this to block forever. But this isn't likely your underlying problem.

Your underlying problem is exactly as you expect: you're calling `scheduledTimer` and `invalidate` on the wrong threads. The rules are (a) they must be called on the same thread, and (b) that thread must have an active RunLoop (this is not always available). The easiest way to ensure that happens is to always run Timer operations on the main queue. Doing that, you can get rid of `timerLock`.

```
private func startTimer() {
    Task { @MainActor in
        if (timer != nil) {
            return
        }
        logger.error("Starting timer on \(Thread.current)")
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            self.logger.error("Timer fired on \(Thread.current)")
        })
    }
}
```

And similarly for stopTimer.

Comment: You can ignore the lock stuff.  That was just from me tracking down what is going on.

Comment: Forcing both startTimer and stopTImer to run on the main thread does indeed appear to resolve the problem.  Thanks.